# how can I implement two vm allocation policy in one data center in cloudsim?

Tags: java, eclipse, cloud, cloudsim

In cloudsim, when I create an object from a datacenter class, it has just one input parameter for vm allocation policy. In my work, I have 2 kinds of applications in a datacenter and datacenter's vm allocation policy should be different about them.

What shoud I do?

Should I extend 2 class of cloudlet, initialize an `Apptype` for them and overload the `allocateVmTohost` method with 3 parameters (`vm`, `Host`, `CloudletType`)
Or there is a better solution?

http://www.cloudbus.org/cloudsim/examples.html